# How to get a Value fill the entire image?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Let me explain. I want to get a specific value from the z buffer (the closest pixel of a specific object to the camera) and then fill the image with that value in order to Run a Less than Math operator to get a mask of the objects are in front of my object. but I can´t find a way to do it. here is an image of what I´m trying to do. sorry for the convoluted explanation.
[image]

Comment: You're using cryptomatte, but AFAIK it doesn't have anything to say about actual depth.  Have you enabled View Layers -> Passes -> Z?

Comment: I think what you want is that Z pass into math node or color ramp